# Using a publicly accessible research database for Development Data Library (DDL) submissions

Tags: usaidopen

I understand that in some cases if the dataset (that we're submitting to USAID) is maintained on a publicly accessible research database, then DDL submission is not required. Does this publically accessible database have to be approved first? Are there any other rules for doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question, and we’re sorry for taking a while to follow up—we’ve been using the last year or so to make important changes to the DDL that I hope you’ll find valuable.

The DDL is a repository for all data collected in the course of USAID awards, including data that are stored on other publicly accessible research databases. If you have a partner account and you have received Editor privileges on the platform (see our [User Guide](https://data.usaid.gov/stories/s/Creating-an-Account/938e-nmfj) for more information), you can create a data asset that contains no spreadsheet-formatted datasets, but instead, describes the data and links to an external database. See the DDL User Guide section on [Adding Datasets](https://data.usaid.gov/stories/s/Adding-Datasets/2jvq-bbpd) for more information.

Please don’t hesitate to follow up on this thread or email us at [dataservices@usaid.gov](http://mailto:dataservices@usaid.gov) if you have any other questions.

Hope this helps!

Robin, USAID Data Services